# Шукаємо вдалий переклад терміна Governance

Tags: переклад, from-english, терміни

Перекладаємо PMBOK Lexicon та ISO Vocabulary в рамках проєкту "PMBOK та PM ISO українською". Намагаємося підбирати прості переклади, але такі, що передають сенс оригінальних англійських термінів.

Є ціла низка термінів, пов'язаних із Governance:

- [Governance](https://www.iso.org/obp/ui/#iso:std:iso:tr:21506:ed-1:v1:en:term:3.25) (ISO)
- [Governing Body](https://www.iso.org/obp/ui/#iso:std:iso:tr:21506:ed-1:v1:en:term:3.26) (ISO)
- [Portfolio Governance](https://www.iso.org/obp/ui/#iso:std:iso:tr:21506:ed-1:v1:en:term:3.44) (ISO)
- [Programme governance](https://www.iso.org/obp/ui/#iso:std:iso:tr:21506:ed-1:v1:en:term:3.53) (ISO)
- [Project governance](https://www.iso.org/obp/ui/#iso:std:iso:tr:21506:ed-1:v1:en:term:3.60) (ISO)

Визначення термінів можна подивитися за посиланнями вище.

Складність перекладу полягає у тому, що потрібно одночасно перекласти декілька термінів так, щоб розрізнити їх зміст. Це такі терміни:

- Management (наприклад: Project Management, Program Management, Portfolio Management)
- Leadership
- Governance (наприклад: Project governance, Program governance, Portfolio governance)
- Stewardship (новий термін в PMBOK 7)

Comment: [На фейсбуці](https://www.facebook.com/ukrse/posts/2954006624725364?comment_id=2954019924724034) пропонують подивитися [Стандарти на системи керування: міжнародний та європейський досвід і його запровадження в Україні / М. Д. Гінзбург, С. Є. Коваленко, А. М. Клюнь // Стандартизація. Сертифікація. Якість. - 2016. - № 1. - С. 7-16](http://www.irbis-nbuv.gov.ua/cgi-bin/irbis_nbuv/cgiirbis_64.exe?I21DBN=LINK&P21DBN=UJRN&Z21ID=&S21REF=10&S21CNR=20&S21STN=1&S21FMT=ASP_meta&C21COM=S&2_S21P03=FILA=&2_S21STR=ssia_2016_1_3). (У якій мірі це доречно, мені важко сказати, я не спеціаліст.)

Comment: Чи розглядали ви *врядування?*

Comment: Щодо *stewardship,* то спробуйте *опікунство.*